# TFS Deployment times out, when using an existing Build

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild

I'm trying to deploy an existing build with the "LabDefaultTemplate.11.xaml".

My problem is, that the build times out, as soon as I use an existing build. Here are the last steps including details and the timeout exception:
See https://i.stack.imgur.com/po1i6.png

I have two different servers. The first has TFS 2013 with Build Service, Controller and Agent installed on it. The second is thought to be used for Testing and has a Test-Controller and Agent on it (configured as a Standard-Environment in MS Test-Manager).

- Build Service Account is a Domain-Admin
- Build Connection to TFS goes with a TFS-Admin
- Test Controller Service Login Account is a Local-Admin (mirrored on the Build-Server) and earlier tried with the Domain-Admin
- Test Controller TFS-Connection also with a TFS-Admin
- Test Controller Lab Service Account is not used, earlier also tried with the Domain-Admin

When I set the build to use the latest TFS-Build it runs into the timeout.
And when i set the path to use a Build from a specific location to the Build Directory on the Build-Server it all just works fine.

The difference between a working build and the timeout described above can be seen in this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPM07.png

Has anyone an idea where I'm struggling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was, that my previous builds only "partially succeeded" because they had some failing unit tests. The setting to use the  only uses fully successful builds. So the latest build which was used had no drop folder configured.

I received no info about that, until I saw it in the logs. My fault was to never check, which build really is used as the latest.